# cvs - can I get one trigger per commit (instead of one trigger per file)?

Tags: triggers, cvs

I would like to trigger a Jenkins build job when someone checks a file into CVS, the problem I'm having right now is that when I check in several files in one command (e.g. "cvs commit file1.txt file2.txt"), the trigger I have in loginfo gets called once for each file.

Is there a CVS trigger that triggers once per commit, instead of once per file?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I don't know how Jenkins hooks into CVS, but CVS is a file-based revision system so you may have trouble getting it to work on a whole commit basis.